# TestNG @Dataprovider

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, dataprovider

I have the following requirements for my Java project without TestNG but I added the `@Test` Annotation to run the class.

```
1. Find the classes which are all annotated with `@controller` in the class path
2. Find the methods which are annotated with `@Requestmapping`
3. Infer all the method properties for each classes
4. Load Known details from Excel(Method name, HttpResponsecode, username, password)
5. Send HttpPost or HttpGet or HttpPUT
```

Now I would like the convert the above functionality from 1 to 4 into `@DataProvider` and call the `@Test` Method. How can I do this?

Sample code is :

```
package com.hexgen.reflection.integration;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.hexgen.reflection.request.MethodInfoRO;
import com.hexgen.reflection.request.MethodParamsInfoRO;
import com.hexgen.reflection.support.HexgenControllerClassFinder;
import com.hexgen.reflection.support.HexgenWebAPITestConstants;
import com.hexgen.reflection.support.LoadMethodDetailsInfoFromExcel;

/**
 *  
 * @author anthony
 *
 */
public class HexgenWebAPITest {

    /**
     * This class finds the method which are not secured 
     * and makes sure that the method which are secured works properly
     */

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Test
    public void hexgenWebAPITest( ) {

        int statusCode=0;
        String[] requestMappingValues=null;
        String[] parametersDefinedForMethod=null;
        String strClassname="";
        String strClassNameToFix="";
        String requestingMethod="";
        String uri="";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        List<MethodParamsInfoRO> tempParamsList = null;
        List<String> notSecuredMethodsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String,String> requestingMethodMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        Map<String,String> methodsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String,List> paramsDetailsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List>();
        Map<String,String> urlDetailsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String,MethodInfoRO> knownGoodMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, MethodInfoRO>();

        HexgenControllerClassFinder hexgenClassUtils = new HexgenControllerClassFinder();
        HttpClientRequests httpRequest = new HttpClientRequests();
        MethodParamsInfoRO methodParams ;
        LoadMethodDetailsInfoFromExcel methodDetails = new LoadMethodDetailsInfoFromExcel();

        Class cls;
        try {
            List controllerClassNames = hexgenClassUtils.findControllerClasses(HexgenWebAPITestConstants.BASE_PACKAGE);
            Iterator<Class> className = controllerClassNames.iterator();
            while(className.hasNext())
            {
                Class obj = className.next(); 
                    cls = Class.forName(obj.getName());
                    Method[] methods = cls.getDeclaredMethods();

                    for (Method method : methods) {

                        RequestMapping requestMappingAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class); // gets the method which is maped with RequestMapping Annotation

                        if(requestMappingAnnotation !=null){ // requestMappingAnnotation if condition Starts 
                            PreAuthorize preAuthorizeAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(PreAuthorize.class); // gets the method which is maped with PreAuthorize Annotation
                            if(preAuthorizeAnnotation == null){ // preAuthorizeAnnotation if condition Starts 
                                notSecuredMethodsList.add("Class : "+obj.getName()+"  Method : "+method.getName());
                            } // preAuthorizeAnnotation if condition Ends  

                            requestMappingValues = requestMappingAnnotation.value(); // to get the url value
                            RequestMethod[] requestMethods = requestMappingAnnotation.method(); // to get the request method type
                            requestingMethod = requestMethods[0].name();
                            methodsMap.put(requestMappingValues[0],method.getName());
                            //Following lines to get the request url and the requesting method type
                            urlDetailsMap.put(method.getName(), requestMappingValues[0]);
                            requestingMethodMap.put(method.getName(), requestingMethod);

                            Class[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
                            LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer lcl = new LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer();
                            parametersDefinedForMethod = lcl.getParameterNames(method);

                            tempParamsList = new ArrayList();
                            for (int i=0;i<parameterTypes.length;i++) { // check the parameter type and put them in to a ArrayList
                                methodParams = new MethodParamsInfoRO();
                                Class parameterType=parameterTypes[i];
                                strClassNameToFix = parameterType.getName();
                                strClassname =strClassNameToFix.replaceAll(HexgenWebAPITestConstants.PATTERN_TO_REMOVE,HexgenWebAPITestConstants.PATH_VARIABLE_TO_REPLACE).replaceAll(HexgenWebAPITestConstants.PATTERN_TO_REMOVE_SEMICOLON,HexgenWebAPITestConstants.PATH_VARIABLE_TO_REPLACE);

                                methodParams.setDataType(strClassname);
                                methodParams.setVariableDefined(parametersDefinedForMethod[i]);

                                    if(parameterType.isArray()){
                                        methodParams.setArray(true);
                                    }
                                     if(parameterType.isPrimitive()){
                                        methodParams.setPrimitive(true);
                                     } 
                                    //FIXME find some better way to address this problem
                                    if (strClassname.equals("java.math.BigDecimal")|| strClassname.equals("java.lang.String")|| strClassname.equals("boolean")) {
                                        methodParams.setPrimitive(true);
                                    }
                                    tempParamsList.add(methodParams);
                            }
                            paramsDetailsMap.put(method.getName(),tempParamsList);
                            //paramsList.add(tempParamsList);

                        }//requestMappingAnnotation if condition Ends 

                    }

            }


               /** HTTPResponeCodes
                * =================
                * 1. 200 Response Successful 
                * 
                * 2. 400 Bad Request(The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.)
                * 
                * 3. 403 Forbidden
                * 
                * 4. 405 Method Not Allowed (The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.)
                * 
                * 5. 500 Internal Server Error(The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.)
                * 
                */

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I have used apache-httpclient 4.0 for server communications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the following, hope this works and helps you. Good Luck.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "HexgenControllersData")
    public void hexgenControllersTest(KnownGoodInfo knownGoodInfoRO, Object[] methodInfoObject) throws Exception {
        int httpResponseStatus=0;
        String requestURL = "";

        HttpClient authenticationObject = null;
        MethodProperties methodPropertiesRO = null;
        HttpRequestHandler httpRequestHandler = new HttpRequestHandler();

        methodPropertiesRO = (MethodProperties) methodInfoObject[0];
        //Attempts to login to hexgen application
        authenticationObject = httpRequestHandler.loginToHexgen(knownGoodInfoRO.getUser(), knownGoodInfoRO.getPassword());
        requestURL = HexgenControllersTestConstants.DEFAULT_URL + methodPropertiesRO.getUrl();
        //Attempts to send url request and gets the http response code
        httpResponseStatus = httpRequestHandler.handleHTTPRequest(authenticationObject, requestURL,methodPropertiesRO.getRequestingMethod(),(List) methodInfoObject[1]);
        Assert.assertEquals(knownGoodInfoRO.getHttpResponse(), httpResponseStatus);
    }
    @DataProvider(name = "HexgenControllersData")
    public static Object[][] dataProviderForSecurityinference() {
        String[] requestMappingValues = null;
        String[] parametersDefinedForMethod = null;
        String strClassname = "";
        String strClassNameToFix = "";
        String requestingMethod = "";

        List<MethodParamsInfo> tempParamsList = null;
        List<String> notSecuredMethodsList = null;
        Map<String, List> methodParametersMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List>();
        Map<String, MethodProperties> methodPropertiesMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, MethodProperties>();
        Map<String, KnownGoodInfo> knownGoodMap = null;

        MethodParamsInfo methodParams = null;
        MethodProperties methodPropertiesRO = null;
        DataProviderForHexgenControllers dataProviderForHexgenControllers = null;

        try {
            dataProviderForHexgenControllers = new DataProviderForHexgenControllers();
            Class classInstance;
            List controllerClassNames = dataProviderForHexgenControllers.findControllerClasses(HexgenControllersTestConstants.BASE_PACKAGE);
            Iterator<Class> classNames = controllerClassNames.iterator();
            notSecuredMethodsList = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (classNames.hasNext()) {
                Class className = classNames.next();
                classInstance = Class.forName(className.getName());
                Method[] methods = classInstance.getDeclaredMethods();

                for (Method method : methods) {
                    // gets the method which is maped with RequestMapping Annotation
                    RequestMapping requestMappingAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);

                    // requestMappingAnnotation if condition Starts
                    if (requestMappingAnnotation != null) {
                        PreAuthorize preAuthorizeAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(PreAuthorize.class);  
                        // record the method name if it is not annotated with preAuthorize
                        if (preAuthorizeAnnotation == null) {
                            notSecuredMethodsList.add("Class : "+className.getName() + "  Method : " + method.getName());
                        }

                        // to get the url value
                        requestMappingValues = requestMappingAnnotation.value();

                        // to get the request method type
                        RequestMethod[] requestMethodWithURL = requestMappingAnnotation .method();

                        requestingMethod = requestMethodWithURL[0].name();

                        // Attempts to get the request url and the requesting method type
                        methodPropertiesRO = new MethodProperties();
                        methodPropertiesRO.setRequestingMethod(requestingMethod);
                        methodPropertiesRO.setUrl(requestMappingValues[0]);
                        methodPropertiesMap.put(method.getName(),methodPropertiesRO);

                        Class[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
                        LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer localVariableDefinedDiscover = new LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer();
                        parametersDefinedForMethod = localVariableDefinedDiscover
                                .getParameterNames(method);

                        tempParamsList = new ArrayList();
                        // check the parameter type and put them in to a
                        // ArrayList
                        for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {
                            methodParams = new MethodParamsInfo();
                            Class parameterType = parameterTypes[i];
                            strClassNameToFix = parameterType.getName();
                            strClassname = strClassNameToFix .replaceAll( HexgenControllersTestConstants.PATTERN_TO_REMOVE,HexgenControllersTestConstants.PATTERN_TO_REPLACE)
                                           .replaceAll( HexgenControllersTestConstants.PATTERN_TO_REMOVE_SEMICOLON, HexgenControllersTestConstants.PATTERN_TO_REPLACE);

                            methodParams.setDataType(strClassname);
                            methodParams.setVariableDefined(parametersDefinedForMethod[i]);

                            if (parameterType.isArray()) {
                                methodParams.setArray(true);
                            }
                            if (parameterType.isPrimitive()) {
                                methodParams.setPrimitive(true);
                            }
                            // FIXME find some better way to address this problem
                            if (strClassname .equals(HexgenControllersTestConstants.BIGDECIMAL)
                                    || strClassname .equals(HexgenControllersTestConstants.STRING)
                                    || strClassname .equals(HexgenControllersTestConstants.BOOLEAN)) 
                                {
                                    methodParams.setPrimitive(true);
                                }
                            tempParamsList.add(methodParams);
                        }
                        methodParametersMap.put(method.getName(),tempParamsList);

                    }// requestMappingAnnotation if condition Ends

                }
            }
            dataProviderForHexgenControllers = new DataProviderForHexgenControllers();
            knownGoodMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, KnownGoodInfo>();
            knownGoodMap =  dataProviderForHexgenControllers.getKnownGoodMap(HexgenControllersTestConstants.KNOWN_GOOD_FILE_PATH);
        } catch (Exception dataProviderForSecurityinferenceException) {
            dataProviderForSecurityinferenceException.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Object[]> hexgenSecurityInferenceData = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        for (String methodName:knownGoodMap.keySet()) {
            hexgenSecurityInferenceData.add(new Object[] {
                    knownGoodMap.get(methodName),
                new Object[] {
                    methodPropertiesMap.get(methodName),
                    methodParametersMap.get(methodName)
                }
             });
         }
        Object[][] securityInferenceData = hexgenSecurityInferenceData.toArray(new Object[0][]);
        return  securityInferenceData;
    }
```

and let me know the results and try not to forget to accept this answer if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @Antony i have completed this question with the same approach you have provided. Thanks for the post and +1